# How to make WCF NetTcpBinding working with TLS

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

I am new to WCF.
I have a simple WCF Server/Ciient C# (Framwork 4.8) application that uses the NetTcpBinding protocol. The application sends a message to the Server, and Server returns the message back with a datetime stamp.

I need to make the application working with TLS.

Server:

```
host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));

NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();

binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;

binding.Security.Transport.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls11 | 
SslProtocols.Tls;

host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), binding, new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:8888/implementclass"));

host.Open();
```

Client:

```
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();    

binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;

binding.Security.Transport.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls; 

EndpointAddress epa = new EndpointAddress($"net.tcp://{txtIPAddress.Text}:8888/implementclass");

ChannelFactory<IMyService> chn = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(binding, epa);

chn.CreateChannel();
```

ServiceContract:

[OperationContract]

```
string Send(string s);
```

When Client/Server run on two different computers ( Firewall is disabled on both),
the following error appers :

**The server has rejected the client credentials**

The Client/Server work on the same PC installed.
Also the Client/Server work when I am using unsecure connection:

```
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None
```

How to make the application working using the TLS protocol?

Answer (score 0):

You can try set the ClientCredentialType property for Transport mode,and the following code sets the property to Windows.

```
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType =TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

```
<security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
</security>
```

> How to make the application working using the TLS protocol?
> You can read the following articles:
> [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls)
>
> [How to enable TLS 1.2 on clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client)